# Can template deduction guides call constexpr functions?

Tags: c++, c++17, constexpr, template-argument-deduction

I have my own fixed-size array type I want to be `constexpr` constructible from an `std::initializer_list` without having to explicitly define the size template argument.

I thought I'd be able to use a template deduction guide but it looks like it's not treating `std::initializer_list::size()` as a constexpr function for it.

Here's an example of trying to make a deduction guide for `std::array` (which is similar to my type and has the same problem):

```
namespace std
{
    template<typename T> array(initializer_list<T> initialiserList) -> array<T, initialiserList.size()>;
}
static constexpr std::array myArray = {1,2,3};
static constexpr std::array myArray2 = {{1,2,3}};
```

I've tried on MSVC and Clang, both give roughly the same errors:
`myArray` has an error complaining about too many arguments to the function.
`myArray2` says "substitution failure [with T = int]: non-type template argument is not a constant expression"

I tried putting `constexpr` in front of the deduction guide or the function argument but neither appears to be allowed, so it appears that the deduction guide is invalid even though it should work fine in a `constexpr` context.

Is there a way to make this work without going down the `make_array()` route?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do:

```
template <class T, class... U>
array(T, U...) -> array<T, 1 + sizeof...(U)>;
```

The problem is not that you cannot call `constexpr` functions in deduction guides. You can. This example is ridiculous, but works:

```
constexpr size_t plus_one(size_t i) { return i + 1; }

template <class T, class... U>
array(T, U...) -> array<T, plus_one(sizeof...(U))>;
```

The problem is that function parameters are not `constexpr` objects, so you cannot invoke `constexpr` member functions on them if those member functions read kind of local state.

Answer (score 8):

> Is there a way to make this work without going down the `make_array()` route?

Why don't you try with the following deduction guide ?

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
array(T const (&)[N]) -> array<T, N>;
```

This way, the argument in `myArray2 = {{1,2,3}}` isn't interpreted as a `std::initializer_list` (that as argument can't be considered `constexpr`, so it's `size()` can't be used for a template argument) but as a C-style array.

So can be deduced, as template arguments, type and size (`T` and `N`) and also the size (`N`) can be used as template argument.

Answer (score 2):

Parameter/argument values are not `constexpr`.

You might use variadic template to know size at compile time, or type with know size (`std::array` or C-array reference).